# Is it OK to use NSBinaryStoreType for this data model?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, database, core-data

(First Entity)

- `NSString` (20 characters on average)

(Second Entity)

- `NSDate`
- `NSDate`
- `NSNumber` (0 or 1 for boolean use)
- `NSString` (1000 characters on average)

The two entities have a to-many relationship (first_entity <<->> second_entity).

---

Let's say that there will be, on average, 100 of the first entity, and 1000 of the second entity.
How does a binary store hold up to this?

What if I up my numbers, and there are 1000 of the first entity and 10000 of the second entity? How does it look now?

Any input appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you open a binary store, all its contents will be loaded into memory. So your application needs to instantiate about 10 000 objects in the first case and 100 000 in the second case (the object IDs + the cache nodes + the cache nodes' dictionaries + the relationships + the attributes). I wouldn't be surprised if your application hanged for a couple of seconds (or longer).

Moreover, storing 10 000 strings of 1000 unichar (2 bytes) characters uses about 20MB in memory (but your whole graph will be even larger) which is a lot for an iOS device.

I did not test the footprint of loading that data model from a binary store on my device but I think you really should not `NSBinaryStoreType` in this case.

Comment: SQLite do the same thing. It loads all data to memory.

Comment: @IvanSurzhenko no it doesn't. According to Apple: _In a deployed application that uses a large data set, you typically use an SQLite store, since this offers high performance and does not require that the entire object graph reside in memory_. ([Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdPersistentStores.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002875-SW4))